# Why can't I access property directly if it is accessed by another process?

Tags: javascript, properties, locking, requestanimationframe

I started to port my canvas animation to a enclosed class, but what got me really frustrated is that, for some reason my `canvas` context could not access an animated property like it used to. That was until, just for shits and giggles, I passed in not the property but a reference of that property (copy if you will)

I want to understand why it is a problem to access a property that is used by another process?

**Note:** TweenLite ticker is using `requestAnimationFrame()` to perform udpates.

Here is cut down code representing the issue, if I'm accessing `self.props.ctxProps.angle` directly the `context` uses initial value `0` and after animation is done the final value `-1.999 * Math.PI`, only when I use a reference variable `context` will access the intermediate values which are between `0` and `-1.999 * Math.PI`:

```
var sample = (function () {

    var self = new Object();

    self.props = {
        ctx: document.getElementById("loading-ring").getContext("2d"),
        ctxProps: {
            canvasX: 50,
            canvasY: 50,
            radius: 50,
            angle: 0.0
        }
    };

    self.updateCanvas = function () {
        // TODO: Ask stacakoverflow
        var ref_angle = self.props.ctxProps.angle;

        self.props.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

        self.props.ctx.beginPath();
        self.props.ctx.moveTo(self.props.ctxProps.canvasX, self.props.ctxProps.canvasY);
        self.props.ctx.arc(
            self.props.ctxProps.canvasX,
            self.props.ctxProps.canvasY,
            self.props.ctxProps.radius, 0,
            ref_angle); // This works - Accesses the intermediate values 
            //self.props.ctxProps.angle); // This does not work - Accesses only start and end values
        self.props.ctx.fill();
    }

    self.run = function () {
        TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener('tick', self.updateCanvas);
        TweenLite.to(self.props.ctxProps, 100, { angle: -1.999 * Math.PI });
    }

    return {
        run: self.run
    }

})();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it does not work"? What is the code supposed to do and what does it do? I don't see any reason why that shouldn't "work", so I assume you are drawing the wrong conclusions from whatever you observe. An executable example would certainly be helpful.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated OP. If I'm accessing `self.props.ctxProps.angle` directly the `context` uses initial value `0` and after animation is done the final value `-1.999 * Math.PI`, only when I use a reference variable `context` will access the intermediate values which are between `0` and `-1.999 * Math.PI`

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, unless I misunderstand the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0rxx8Lg5/